# Repeated calls to knnMatch takes long time

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on a real time system and matching `ORB` features using `BFMatcher(cv::NORM_HAMMING)`

I'm matching a single image features to 9 others in a loop using

```
matcher->knnMatch(m_descriptorMat, matches, 2)
```

Usually the matching takes 1-2 ms per loop iteration (1 image per iteration)

matcher is trained before starting the matching.

On occasions, a single iteration would slow down and take ~200-300 ms (and the following iteration would again be 1-2 ms)

The size of each descriptor is ~300-400 features (8-bit)

Any ideas why repeated calls to the **same** matcher would suddently slow down?

Comment: [Possibly related (although I have no idea)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array)